# Create the directory structure using mkdir and touch

Tags: linux, shell, unix, touch, mkdir

I am learning Unix online and i came across this question to create a hierarchical structure. I have created the directories using mkdir command but I am stuck while creating the files inside directory.

My command for creating directories is

```
mkdir -p mydir/{colors/{basic,blended}, shape,animals/{mammals,reptiles}}
```

I want to create files such as red,green,blue inside colors folder, lizard, snakes inside reptiles folder and so on.
Please help!

Comment: refer the below link. its not a programming question though.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/731721/is-there-a-way-to-create-multiple-directories-at-once-with-mkdir

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: An identical question was posted by a different account 2 days later to AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/928496/

Answer (score 1):

```
touch mydir/colors/{red,green,blue} mydir/animals/reptilies/{lizard,snake}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
mkdir -p mydir/{colors/{basic,blended},shape,animals/{mammals,reptiles}}
touch mydir/{colors/{basic/{red,blue,green},blended/{yellow,orange,pink}},shape/{circle,square,cube},animals/{mammals/{platypus,bat,dog},reptiles/{snakes,crocodile,lizard}}}
```

Comment: Format your code properly. Also instead of dumping the code alone.Explain the code properly which is considered as a good answer

Comment: Also if you use code from other sites, please be sure to cite it - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461782/copy-the-file-red-to-blended-directory-in-unix.